# need clarification to upload the image to server

Tags: iphone, ios

I am new to iPhone development So **Can any one explain about the line while uploading an image to the server** ?

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://www.mysite.com/edit_profile.php";
```

**What does the line mean???**

If we are writing the same code in our new project **what shall we need to write there**?

**How to check whether the image added or not**?

I have watched the youtube video

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQXaJO36I7Y

There it was upload.php and that .php file was there in her system.
 **What shall i need to do if i wrote the same code in my application?**

Comment: Are you making your own server?

Comment: explain ques in more deatail ,whether u want coding help or somehing else?? if you want code help then give correct URL and also other parameters to pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to understand below code its simple http post method to send data (here in our case image post data) to server...

```
- (id)initWithURL:(NSString *)url requestDataForImage:(NSData *)dataForImage imagename:(NSString*)imagename
```

{

```
 if (self = [super init])
    {
        initrequeststring=@"Sourceimagetype";
         NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
        url = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
        [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body1 = [NSMutableData data];
    [body1 appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //int r = arc4random() % 480000;
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"SourceImage\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", imagename];
    [body1 appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:str] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body1 appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding : NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body1 appendData:[NSData dataWithData:dataForImage]];
    [body1 appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body1];


    con=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if(con)
    {
        webdata=[[NSMutableData data]retain];
    }
}

return self;
```

}

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [webdata setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [webdata appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [app hideLoadingView];

    if ([WSDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(ConnectionFail:)])
    {
        [WSDelegate ConnectionFail:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",error.localizedDescription]];
    }
    else
    {
        connection=nil;
        [connection release];
    }
}
```

in php file on server you can move our file to desired folder..

```
if ($_GET['user_id']!='')
{
    $uploaddir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/streetculture/Images/'.$user_id.'/';
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['SourceImage']['tmp_name'],$uploaddir.$_FILES['SourceImage']['name']);
    $da_created = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    @$Carpic = $_FILES['SourceImage']['name'];
    $thumbname='th_'.$Carpic;
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $Carpic;
    $tx_image = $Carpic;
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($uploadfile) ;
    $ratio=2;
    $modwidth = $width / $ratio; 
    $modheight = $height / $ratio;
    $modwidth=round($modwidth, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
    $modheight=round($modheight, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
    $tn = imagecreatetruecolor($modwidth, $modheight) ; 
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadfile) ; 
    imagecopyresampled($tn, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $modwidth, $modheight, $width, $height) ;
    imagejpeg($tn,$uploaddir . $thumbname, 100) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uploading an image means you upload it to some server,It has a path to where image should be uploaded

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://www.mysite.com/edit_profile.php";
```

means you are making a string url of that path ,which is used to prepare a url request to send  tha data to the server path

Comment: /Users/vasanthi/Desktop/Trainings/Net trainings/upload/upload.php this is the location i need to upload my image in my system if i gave the path like this and run my application and checked in the location /Users/vasanthi/Desktop/Trainings/Net trainings/upload/upload.php but i didn't find the image?

Comment: so what shall i need to do? if i want to check the image ?                     Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

The string in your code is a URL. (see this wiki for more info: [Uniform Resource Locator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator) ).

When uploading a file to a server you may (but are not forced to) use a HTTP POST request as described in [RFC 1867](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1867), "Form-based File Upload in HTML".

On iOS you can use `NSURLConnection` to accomplish this, or use a third party framework.

SO contains a wealth of information how to upload files to a server.